# Change link text to icon link

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I wanted to ask if anyone of you there who knows the syntax to change the link into the Icon that when clicked will automatically download in CodeIgniter.

I have a download link but I do not know where to insert the icon where and how? anyone who knows please teach me thanks

The syntax for the downloads I got

```
        <th field="file" width="50" sortable="true" data-options="formatter:function(val){
            return '<a href=\'<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/'+val+'\' target=\'_blank\'>' + val + '</a>';
        }">File</th>
```

Comment: just modify your link like this
<a class="link_with_image" href=\'<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/'+val+'\' target=\'_blank\'></a>

and add style to the class
<style>
.link_with_image{
background-image: url('your desired image');
}
</style>

Comment: thank you for answering: D 
but the grid disappeared when I give class="link_with_image" in tag <a href> :( can you help me one more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify the class like this

```
<style>
    .link_with_image{
        background-image: url('your desired image');
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    }
</style>
```

you can change the with and height as desired

Comment: This is very helpful thanks :D 
if you could help me again next time :D thanks a lot :)